# scrpage2 with scrbook. Chapter on left and right header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2, scrbook

I started using `scrpage2` with `scrbook`. First thing I don't understand is the usage of `\automark[chapter]{chapter}`. How could I let display chapter on left and right header. I managed to do that with subsection and chapter etc. But the first seems to be more difficult..

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
```

between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

```
 \pagestyle{scrheadings}
 \ohead{\pagemark} 
 \cehead{\leftmark} 
 \cohead{\rightmark} 
 \ofoot[]{}
```

%%%%%%

```
\chapter{Intro}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 


\chapter{Different Chapter}
\automark[subsection]{chapter}
```

etc.

Comment: What do you need, precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand, `\headmark` refers to the chapter on even pages (left hand) and to sections on odd pages (right hand).

If you say

```
\ihead{\leftmark}
```

you'll have the chapter title in the inner side of the header on all pages, without any need to give `\automark` commands.

Comment: Thanks! I would further more need to change the `\leftmark` and `\rigthmark` settings for each new chapter, when I want them to change.

Comment: @algomachine I can't understand

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51549/no-numberings-no-numbers-section-chapter-subsection-etc-in-header) .