# No numberings, no numbers (section, chapter, subsection etc.) in header?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, koma-script, scrpage2

I am using `scrpage2` with `scrbook.` I would like to have no numbers or numbering of sections, chapters, etc.. in the header. How can I achieve that?

I have the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}   
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{% 
\normalfont\scshape} 

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%Formatting
\ohead{\pagemark} 
\cehead{\leftmark}
\cohead{\leftmark}
\ofoot[]{} 

\chapter{Intro}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\cehead{\leftmark} 
\cohead{\rightmark} 
\automark[subsection]{chapter}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\automark[section]{chapter}

\chapter{Final Chapter}
\cehead{\leftmark} 
\cohead{\leftmark} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` in your preamble solve your problem? It removes the numbering from all areas in your MWE, not only the header.

Comment: Hmm no, I already use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` to get rid of the numbering for subsections. But I want the numbering of sections and chapters in the content and in the table of content.  (In my case I got rid of the numbers in the ToC too, but thats not relevant.. )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want to turn off numbering *only* in the header: As you are using a `KOMA-Script` class, simply redefine `\chaptermarkformat` and `\sectionmarkformat` (and, if applicable, `\subsectionmarkformat`) to do nothing.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```